# Get extensions to work on multi store(Onestepcheckout)

Tags: magento

I've set up a Magento website, with 2 stores in it, on the same domain (subdirectory)

Example:
www.site.com (main site)
www.site.com/second (second site)

My problem is, that some of my extensions dosen't seem to work cross site, like OneStepCheckout ex. When I go to checkout on (Second site) It's just going to an empty page.

Anyone tried this? Does anyone know a solution?

> **I solved it by copying the templates to right theme folders.**

Comment: Is it a single Magento installation or 2 different installations?

Comment: Single installation, with 2 store fronts.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? Do you get an error message or just standard OnePageCheckout?

Comment: Please mark your answer as "Accepted" (click the checkmark next to it) when you have the chance, rather than editing "solved" into the title. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This was simply (Error 40).. Forgot to Copy the Template files to the new store's Template directory as stated in Onestepcheckout's users manual.

Answer (score 1):

if you get a empty page then you need to verify

- if it is not a php error on your site - see php error_log or enable error reporting from index.php
- if your theme fallback is set up properly - if it falls back to app/design/frontend/base/default/

Comment: I've figured it out, I've forgotten to copy the Template files of Onestepcheckout to the new shop.. Simple mistake, greatly disturbing :)